Error in SwiftHealthPlugin.swift when deploying XCode in Flutter development
I am currently developing a mobile app in Flutter, but when I build iOS, I suddenly get the following error and cannot build.
I would like to know if anyone knows the cause of this problem.
SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:315:41 Cannot find 'dbUnit' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:316:42 Cannot find 'dbUnit' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:317:79 Cannot find 'frequency' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:318:13 Cannot find 'sensitivityPoints' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:332:13 Cannot find 'audiogram' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:332:61 Cannot find 'sensitivityPoints' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:335:13 Cannot find 'audiogram' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:335:61 Cannot find 'sensitivityPoints' in scope

SwiftHealthPlugin.swift:338:30 Cannot find 'audiogram' in scope

For MBaaS, we are still using Firebase. Best regards.

"Questions seeking debugging help ('why isn't this code working?') must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example." and Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example

Those errors could be a number of things including incorrect file paths, outdated plugins, outdated CocoaPods (if that's being used) as well as missing dependencies. We would need a lot more info to know. If you're using CocoaPods, including your podfile in the question may be revealing.
